# how to install package manual in texlive 2015

Tags: packages, installing

How to install package `imfellEnglish` manually   in **texlive2015**
[image]

Comment: are you sure it is not installed already? `texdoc imfellEnglish` shows me the example document.

Comment: then `tlmgr install imfellEnglish` should install it (but it is part of the default installation, I did nothing special to get it)

Comment: yes i am sure this package is not installed ( http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/imfellenglish/ )

Comment: I found a mistake when put `tlmgr install imfellEnglish` please i want to install manual

Comment: Why install it manually? Why not install it with texlive's package manager?

Comment: To show an image edit the question, not a comment and use the image upload in the editor

Comment: this is the erorre `
lmgr install imfellEnglish

lmgr.pl: package repository http://osl.ugr.es/CTQN/systems/texliue/tlnet
lmgr.pl install: package imfellEnglish not present in repository.
lmgr.pl: action install returned a warning.`

Comment: sorry i cannt  upload image in comment

Comment: That's a locale/`tlmgr` problem. It has nothing to do with imfellEnglish, I don't think. I know nothing about Windows but can you set your locale to something standard and boring which it will know?

Comment: I solved the problems by updating `tlmgr` lastest . thank you @cfr @David Carlisle